# How to get message author in nextcord?

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I am making a kick command which display the kicked user name and the kicker user name
in discord.py i know its ctx.message.author but interaction.message.author dont work in nexcord

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Slash command interactions do not have a "message" attribute since nothing is sent until you respond. The message attribute of interaction is specifically for buttons and selects which originate from a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read the documentation for the interaction class [here](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=interaction#nextcord.Interaction.user) and you'll find what you're looking for

`interaction.user` will return the `User` class, of which you can then access the id, and other [attributes](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=interaction#nextcord.User).